# How to use ODBC in Poco (C++)?

Tags: c++, odbc, poco, poco-libraries

I made the choice to peek Poco (the (too) big C++ library) to handle with ODBC connections.

But after digging into this part of the lib `Poco::Data::ODBC`, I'm not figuring out if I am missing something or if some documented functions are simply unimplemented.

Documentation to the ODBC namespace : https://docs.pocoproject.org/current/Poco.Data.ODBC.html

For example, `SQLTables(...)` which is a reimplementation of the Windows ODBC API function of the same signature (Poco has almost all functions named after Windows ODBC Api), looks to be missing. If I use it, I won't get any response.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/odbc/reference/syntax/sqltables-function?view=sql-server-ver15
https://docs.pocoproject.org/current/Poco.Data.ODBC.html#3649

- How do you use ODBC in Poco?
- Do I need to reimplement something, or inherit and specialize?
- Do you have any example using this functions?

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <Poco/Data/SessionFactory.h>
#include <Poco/Data/ODBC/Connector.h>

using namespace Poco::Data;

void main() {
    try {
        ODBC::Connector::registerConnector();
        Session session{ SessionFactory::instance().create(ODBC::Connector::KEY, "Driver={IBM i Access ODBC Driver};SYSTEM=192.168.0.10;DBQ=BASENAME;UID=user;PWD=passwd") };
        if (session.isConnected()) {
            StatementImpl *hstmt = session.createStatementImpl();
            ODBC::SQLTables(hstmt, NULL, 0, NULL, 0, NULL, 0, NULL, 0);
        }
    }
    catch (const Poco::Exception& err) {
        std::cerr << "Error thrown: " << err.displayText() << "\n";
    }
}
```

Resulting to the message:

> "Error thown: Not implemented"

Comment: *If I use it, I won't get any response.* -- You need to explain in more detail.  What do you mean by "won't get any response"?  If the function is missing, then you would get linker errors.

Comment: You're right it's not at compile time (or link). The feedback is at runtime, triggered by the library. I added an example. Just set a valid Connexion String.

Comment: The Poco library comes with full source code.  Have you looked through it to verify that the function is not implemented?